# При частом нажатии одной, двух, трёх и более клавиш одновременно, одна из них в зажатом состоянии перестаёт работать

Tags: клавиатура, ноутбук

При быстром нажатии клавиш (достаточно даже двух) что-то замыкает и зажатая физически клавиша не является зажатой (т.е. чтобы она опять заработала нужно отпустить и снова зажать)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=70BXd9ju414 (тайм-код: 0:54), но лучше с самого начала глянуть видео

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Внутри клавиатуру несколько клавиш соединёно само собой

Comment: Такое происходит с любыми клавишами (хоть соединены, хоть нет). Даже цифра+буква, цифра+цифра, W+F, O+H и так далее

Comment: Думайте это только у вас так происходить?
Если вы не довольные то обращаетесь производителю клавиатуру.
Если не верти то попробуете на другом клавиатуру.

Comment: 1) На двух ноутбуках нету вообще такого и никогда не было. Проверял на двух проводных клавиатурах самых дешёвых и там намного лучше чем клавиатура в новом ноутбуке.
2) В сервисном центре лежал полтора месяца в итоге поменяли корпус (клавиатуру нельзя отдельно поменять на нём, только с корпусом идёт). До замены говорили, что "особенность".

Может ли быть проблема в материнской плате?

Comment: Пожалуйста, если так происходить откройте клавиатуру и посмотрите на схему...